# Telerik DatePicker - how to change the position of the popup button?

Tags: telerik, raddatepicker

how can I make the position of the popup button in the RadCalendar control (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultcs.aspx) to be on the other side, eg:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Rad Telerik, so I'm not sure if there are other ways to do it, but it's possible to make it look like what you are asking by working with CSS.
I've made some tests on the demo page, and this is a CSS that should help you.

```
div.RadPicker table.rcSingle .rcInputCell ~ td {
    position: relative;
    right: 113px;
    display: block;
}

div.RadPicker table.rcSingle .rcInputCell .RadInput {
    position: relative;
    left: 42px;
}
```